# Pull request from dev to master branch doesnt show diff but commits

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have two long-running branches, the default one is master and another one is dev which eventually gets merged into master periodically.

today I updated the dev branch from the master branch by executing

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout dev
git merge origin/master
```

When I try to create a PR from dev to master, I get  `0 files changed` but get 2 commits that were made 2 months ago. ZERO Code diff is expected as we synced the dev branch from the master branch. but as per my understanding, it should also sync the commit history, but it seems it didn't. so my question is did I make any mistake while syncing? is there a better approach in general to do this process? how can I get rid of these two commits(I mean make dev and master similar)

Comment: If the master branch already contains the two commits (in term of diff), then there is really no diff from dev.

Comment: @zigarn yeah, master already has all these code changes that I have in these two commits.

Comment: Is it possible those commits were merge commits of `master` into `dev`, and it's been two months since you merged `dev` back into `master`?

Answer (score 0):

For commits you have committed already, use the `git revert` command, `git revert` command adds a new commit at the end of the chain to cancel changes you would like performed on the commits.

an example
`git revert (unwanted commit)`

after the command has been run, a new commit would be committed to undo the commit you do not want anymore.

```
git revert [--[no-]edit] [-n] [-m parent-number] [-s] [-S[<keyid>]] <commit>…​
git revert (--continue | --skip | --abort | --quit)
```

more information in the Git documentation,

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. can you please tell me exactly how I can use it and what it is going to do?